Docker Desktop 4.30.0 upgrade breaks web services in DevContainer
I have a Dev Container project that runs in VSCode (it's PRQL) that I use with Docker Desktop on both macOS and Windows. It has worked fine for over a year.
Until recently, I had been using Docker Desktop 4.29.0, but I noticed that 4.30.0 was available. And when I upgraded, I found that parts of the Dev Container stopped working. (This occurred for both Mac and Windows machines.)
Details:
The Dev Container has three commands to build various components. For example, task web:run-website builds the public website and displays it through a web browser. The other two components are the Playground and the Book (the documentation).
Prior to the upgrade to 4.30.0, I could run these commands and verify the contents in the browser for all three components
After the upgrade, only the Website works in the browser. For the other two, the Dev Container builds the component, but when I go to the website I get a blank page. Using curl from a host terminal gives this:
?130 % curl -v  http://localhost:5173/playground/playground
*   Trying [::1]:5173...
* connect to ::1 port 5173 failed: Connection refused
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:5173...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 5173
> GET /playground/playground HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:5173
> User-Agent: curl/8.4.0
> Accept: */*

How can I troubleshoot this? Many thanks.

Solution: I solved this by binding to address 0.0.0.0 in the DevContainer commands to run each of the components. (Previously, each of the commands used some variety of "localhost", "127.0.0.1", etc.) Forcing them to use 0.0.0.0 works great.
Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/78534816/1827982 for a hint.
